# Is CO2 in the Pacific Ocean depleted or enriched in Carbon-13 compared to the Atlantic, and why?

Tags: geochemistry, co2, carbon-cycle, thermohaline-circulation, pacific

Due to thermohaline circulation, the Pacific water is more 'aged' so there is a higher amount of total dissolved inorganic carbon (e.g. CO<sub>2</sub>) in the deep Pacific when compared to the Atlantic. However, I don't know how this affects the relative <sup>13</sup>C/<sup>12</sup>C enrichment of the Pacific.
Factors I've thought about:

1. Oxic respiration of buried organic matter is the source of CO<sub>2</sub> in the deep ocean.
2. Deep Pacific water has accumulated more respired CO<sub>2</sub> since the Pacific is at the end of the deep circulation.
3. Algae and microbes fractionate against <sup>13</sup>C in favour of <sup>12</sup>C.

Answer (score 1):

"The decrease in δ<sup>13</sup>C as water flows from the Atlantic to the North Pacific is due mainly to the addition of organically produced material and its subsequent oxidation as it falls through the water column. Marine organic carbon has a δ<sup>13</sup>C of near -25<sup>0</sup>/<sub>00</sub>, hence the addition of this material decreases the δ<sup>13</sup>C of the ΣCO<sub>2</sub>." (from conclusion)

P. M. Kroopnick, *Deep-Sea Research Part a-Oceanographic Research Papers*, 1985, **32**, 57-84.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0198014985900172